# RSpec: The spec_helper.rb is not loaded

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec

I am learning test automation (Ruby, selenium-webdriver, RSpec). But I have hit an issue and cannot resolve it by myself.

The `spec_helper.rb` is (I think) not loaded as described [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/command-line/init-option).

1.) At first I just put a "spec_helper.rb" into the folder "specs"

1.b) I insert in my "spec1.rb"

```
    require 'spec_helper'
```

1.c) I always execute my specs.rb from the folder "specs"

```
    rspec spec1.rb
```

- This hit this Error, inspite of file is at the place:

  ```
  Failure/Error: return gem_original_require(path)

  LoadError:
   cannot load such file -- spec_helper
  # ./spec2.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  No examples found.
  ```

2.) Then I run `rspec --init` in the project-folder, as [described](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/command-line/init-option).

- It generated the file ".rspec" and "specs\spec_helper.rb"
- In the .rspec-file is written default:

  ```
  --require spec_helper
  ```

2.b) Then I wrote in the file "specs\spec_helper.rb": `puts "I am loaded"`

- Here is my code of the "spec\spec_helper.rb":

  ```
  # This file was generated by the `rspec --init` command. Conventionally, all
  # specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
  # The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
  # this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
  # files.

  puts "I am loaded"

  require 'selenium-webdriver'
  require 'rspec/expectations'
  ```
- But nothing comes out there by run `rspec spec.rb`
- my `specs.rb` are in the correct folder
- (Without `spec_helper.rb` my tests are running well.)

3.) At the End I tried again to insert in "specs\spec.rb"

```
    require 'spec_helper'
```

- then certainly it has hit the error again:

  ```
  Failure/Error: return gem_original_require(path)

  LoadError:
   cannot load such file -- spec_helper
  # ./spec2.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  No examples found.
  ```

---

I installed successfully on Win10:

```
ruby 2.3.3

LOCAL GEMS:
bigdecimal (1.2.8)
childprocess (0.8.0)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.3)
ffi (1.9.18 x64-mingw32)
io-console (0.4.5)
json (2.1.0, 1.8.3)
minitest (5.8.5)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (2.1.0)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.1)
rspec (3.6.0)
rspec-core (3.6.0)
rspec-expectations (3.6.0)
rspec-mocks (3.6.0)
rspec-support (3.6.0)
rubyzip (1.2.1)
selenium-webdriver (3.6.0)
test-unit (3.1.5)
```

Comment: You need to put `require 'spec_helper'` at the top of each spec.

Comment: It won't be loaded by magic!

Comment: Please do something with this formatting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I always execute my `specs.rb` from the folder "specs"

Don't.

Run your specs from the **root** folder, i.e. one level above.

Your command should be:

```
# (To run just the one file)
rspec specs\spec.rb

# (To run the full suite)
rspec
```

Side-note: Don't go against the conventions by naming the file `spec1.rb`. All test files should be named like: `<something>_spec.rb`; any other files should be used for helper methods etc.

Comment: I'm coming across this for the first time, and I'm wondering why is it important to run specs from the root folder?

Comment: @TylerM. Whilst you could *theoretically* run code from any location, it's very common for projects to make subtle assumptions about the load path when `require`ing dependencies. So if you run into `LoadError` when running specs from outside the root folder, it's probably much easier to just run the spec from the root folder instead of "fixing" all the code to be load-path-agnostic.

Comment: I see. Is there a method of setting the load path that's something like agreed-upon convention in the Ruby community?

Comment: The "agreed upon convention" is: whatever ruby does by default. Which is essentially just to load the current location plus various internal paths for the core/standard libraries and any 3rd party "gems".

Comment: You can also append extra folders to the load path; a common one is to load the `./bin/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I never `require 'spec_helper'` as it is done automatically by the `.rspec` file. I have followed [Effective Testing with RSpec 3](https://pragprog.com/book/rspec3/effective-testing-with-rspec-3) and did `rspec --init` as you describe.

File `.../spec/spec_helper.rb` :

```
puts "this is #{File.basename(__FILE__)}"
# This file was generated by the `rspec --init` command.
...
```

Test file :

```
# file .../spec/t2_spec.rb

class XXX
end

RSpec.describe XXX do
    describe '#xxx' do
        it 'xxx' do
            puts '... testing ...'
        end
    end
end
```

Execution (RSpec 3.6.0.beta2 on OS X) :

```
$ rspec
this is spec_helper.rb

XXX
  #xxx
... testing ...
    xxx

Finished in 0.001 seconds (files took 0.10816 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

> It generated the file ".rspec" and "specs\spec_helper.rb"

Are you sure your specs directory is `spec` not `specs` ?

**Edit**

I read again your post and see :

> 1.c) I always execute my specs.rb from the folder "specs"

and check if it makes a difference. It does :

```
$ cd spec/
$ ls
examples.txt   spec_helper.rb t2_spec.rb     t_specxxx.rb
$ rspec t2_spec.rb 
... testing ...
.

Finished in 0.00108 seconds (files took 0.10637 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

You can see that `spec_helper.rb` has not been processed :

- message not displayed
- single dot instead of indented documentation, meaning that this code

.

```
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = "doc"
  end
```

has not been executed. As Tom says, run `rspec` from the parent of `lib` and `spec`.

Comment: @Webdriver Edited, don't run from `spec`.

Comment: Thank you verry much for your input. @Tom Lord @BernardK.
I did run `rspec` from `spec`